# partial text matching in middle of word

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene, n-gram

I'm trying to get partial word matching working in solr.

So I have a schema set-up like this:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
         enablePositionIncrements=true ensures that a 'gap' is left to
         allow for accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="1000" side="front" />
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="1000" side="back" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="key"     type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="uid"     type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true" required="true" />

<field name="organisationid"     type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true" required="false" />
<field name="organisationname" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
<field name="organisationcleanname" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />

<field name="practiceareas"     type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="subeditions"     type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

I've indexed all the data i want to and have a few organisation names such as:

- A Kings Name
- Block Me
- All
- King and Wood
- Hacking me Softly

When I do a search using: `(organisationname:king OR organisationcleanname:king) AND practiceareas:20` **Hacking me Softly** doesn't come back in the results (yes it has a practicearea of 20).  Have I set up the NGram incorrectly?

Comment: So having looked though the analyser, it seems that `<filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>` is actually taking **king** out, despite it not being in protwords.txt.

Comment: It would have to be IN protwords if it shouldn't be touched. protwords.txt lists words that the stemmer filter should leave as they are, not words that should be stemmed.

Comment: Well from taking out the reference to the `EnglishPorterFilterFactory` it seems to have solved my problem, however, I'm not sure if it's really solved my problem or if it's a side effect of something else.

Comment: If I remember correctly from your question on IRC, it explains the issue, as the porter filter will remove parts of the word, meaning that you're not seeing the same term as you expect (removing "ing" from the latter part of the word), and then making it unable to match.